# Uncaught exception ‘Twilio\Exceptions\TwilioException’ with message ‘Unknown domain sid’

Tags: php, api, twilio

Hello everyone I trying to integrate  message Api Twilio in php . I did all things same as mentioned in Twilio Documentation but I'm getting error

```
Uncaught exception ‘Twilio\Exceptions\TwilioException’ with message ‘Unknown domain sid’
```

it is giving error on line 796

```
Twilio\Rest\Client->__get(‘sid’) #1 {main} thrown in /home/mydomain/public_html/twilio/Twilio/Rest/Client.php on line 796
```

Can Someone please suggest why I'm getting this error . If anyone want any other information please let me know.

my Code how i trying to do this

```
$status = 'no';
if (isset($_GET['mobile_no']) && ! empty($_GET['mobile_no']))
{
    $mobile_no  = $_GET['mobile_no'];
    $sql_result = "select * from users where user_id='" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "' ";

    $result_user = mysqli_query($x, $sql_result);

    $details_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_user);

    //$user_otp = rand(1000,9999);
    $user_otp    = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
    $msg         = "Your OTP for XYZ is:" . ' ' . $user_otp;
    $current_otp = hash('sha256', $user_otp);

    $sql111 = "update users set mobile_otp='$current_otp',mobile_status='0' where user_id='" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";
    mysqli_query($x, $sql111);
    //use Twilio\Rest\Client; 

    $client->messages->create(
    // the number you'd like to send the message to
        $mobile,
        [
            // A Twilio phone number you purchased at twilio.com/console
            'from' => '+18154274419',
            // the body of the text message you'd like to send
            'body' => 'Sent from a Twilio Trial Account',
        ]
    );

    if ($client->sid)
    {
        $status = 'yes';
    }
}
echo $status;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @RonnieOosting i added the code in question.Thanks.

Comment: First it looks like a problem with: `$sql111 = "update users set mobile_otp='$current_otp',mobile_status='0' where user_id='" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";` Change it to: `$sql111 = "update users set mobile_otp='" . $current_otp . "',mobile_status='0' where user_id='" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";`

Comment: @RonnieOosting , no $mobile is 10 digit mobile number

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message

Comment: @RonnieOosting yes i did all things according to documentation , you can check the program i made,as i know error saying $client don't have any object name "sid"

Comment: Is `+18154274419` your Twilio number or a verified with Twilio number?

Comment: @AlexBaban yes  +18154274419 is verified Twilio number for testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same issue i faced few days ago, This error clearly show the exception   in  `__get(‘sid’)` method  in twilio/Twilio/Rest/Client.php

Here i found a solution of this issue and it works perfectly for me [Uncaught exception ‘Twilio\Exceptions\TwilioException’ with message ‘Unknown domain sid’](https://wecodefy.com/errors/resolved-uncaught-exception-twilioexception-with-message-unknown-domain-sid/)

It looks like there is no method exist with name `getSid()` .
This is the line of code that i added in this method and it solve my issue

```
if(ucfirst($name)=='Sid'){
    $name='AccountSid';
}
```

Hope it will help you too. Thanks

Comment: thanks , this works for me , but your answer means there is problem in Twilio Api Files

Comment: @RahulSaini I am not sure yet but it looks like there is something missing in sdk files, anyway it's worked for me and you also